# How to get user input text from webview in Flutter

Tags: flutter, webview

Am using `webview_flutter: ^4.2.2` for flutter, am calling a login url. Where user will enter user name and password.

Is it possible to get User name in code though `addJavaScriptChannel` ?

I need to know user name, when user click on login button click.

`..addJavaScriptChannel( 'usernameInput', onMessageReceived: (message) { ScaffoldMessenger.of(context) .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(message.message))); }, );`

I would like to get user name, entered by user. when he click on submit or login button click.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with this code?

```
webViewController.runJavaScript('''
 document.querySelector("#signInName").value = "new text";
 .querySelector("input#password").value = "new text";
 document.getElementById("localAccountForm").submit();
''');
```